# How do I integrate base.html in the main page

Tags: python, html, django

Im having trouble extending base.html. ill have the templates below but the problem is the webpage only shows the base.html template when i extend base.html to the main page which is item_list.html and it doesnt show the content i have on the main page.

Thank you in advance for any form of guidance

**item_list.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block content %}

<h2> Here is the list of items </h2>

{% for item in items %}
{{ item }}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

**base.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base.html

> ```
> <html lang="en">
> <head>
> <meta charset="UTF-8">
> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
> <title>Document</title>
> </head>
> <body>
>
> #Add this
> {% block content %}
> {% endblock content %}
>
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```